# Is there a way to use PredicateBuilder with Azure Table Storage?

Tags: linq, azure, lambda, expression, predicatebuilder

Just what it says on the tin, I have a design problem where normally PredicateBuilder would be the obvious answer, but when executing, I get errors such as :

```
The expression 
((([10007].PartitionKey == "df2907ad-2094-4b7a-9796-d077f14b25bc") 
And True) 
And Invoke(f => (True AndAlso Invoke(job => (job.MigrationExecutionId == "5fa0bd4c-4745-4452-8e52-a0329c00dafb"), f)), [10007])) 
is not supported.
```

Any way to use Predicate builder, or some other form of expression tree syntax to build up a query and run it against Azure Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.  ATS offers only limited linq support.

Comment: Do you have any links to  documentation on that?

Comment: Here's everything that ATS supports: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135725.aspx

Comment: Hey Igor, not even a hello?!  I know that Azure has the limited syntax, but I was hoping that I could build up the query (within the bounds of that syntax) via an expression/predicate so that I could build the query more dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) with Azure Table Storage.  Let's say you want to build a query of the format (pseudo code):

```
where partitionkey = "X" and (email = "Y" or email = "Z")
```

This can be done as follows

```
    public string[] GetByEmail(string companyId, string[] emails)
    {
        var inner = PredicateBuilder.New<IssuerTableEntity>(false);
        foreach (var email in emails.Select(x => x.ToLowerInvariant()).Distinct())
        {
            var temp = email;
            inner = inner.Or(x => x.EmailLowercase == temp);
        }

        var outer = PredicateBuilder.New<MyTableEntity>(false);
        outer = outer.And(x => x.PartitionKey == companyId);
        outer = outer.And(inner);

        CloudTable table = GetTable(MyTableName);  
        return table.CreateQuery<MyTableEntity>()
            .Where(outer)
            .Select(x => x.RowKey)
            .ToArray();
    }
```

Note the use of `Distinct()` - this was because I got errors when supplying duplicates.